# Evaluate where a function call originated from

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

Okay so I have a function called `changeHandler` - it is called by several eventListeners in other functions. I want to write several `if` statements that evaluate the source of function call and change the `dataProvider` of my `ComboBox` depending on the originating function. Example: one of the many functions is called `displayCarbs()` and has an eventListener like so:

```
function displayCarbs(event:MouseEvent):void {
myComboBox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler);
}
```

(I've removed all of the unnecessary code from the function above)

The `if` statement inside the `changeHandler` will look something like this:

```
if (****referring function = displayCarbs****) {
    myComboBox2.dataProvider = new DataProvider(carbItems);
    }
```

I've searched high and low for something that can achieve this, but I just don't have a good enough grasp of AS3 or vocabulary to describe what describe what I mean to get the answer from Google.

Comment: Is the goal to know which ComboBox dispatched the event ?

Comment: @prototypical: I have 6 functions called `displayCarbs`, `displayMeat`, `displayVegetables` etc. These functions add a ComboBox to the stage, but the `changeHandler` function listens for the SelectedLabel on the first instance of the ComboBox on each of the "Category" pages being not equal to `null` so that a new instance of a ComboBox appears below. They are all very similiar to one another apart from the fact that the dataProvider for the first ComboBox is different for each.

Comment: (So make what you will of my explanation in answer to your question above)

Comment: So you should be able to determine what you need based on the dataProvider of the ComboBox that dispatched the event ? Since you seem to be saying that the dataProvider for each ComboBox is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of... Couldn't you simply create a text string that updates to the name of function before going to changeHandler then in turn changeHandler can check string content and act accordingly..

```
public var referring_function:String;

function displayCarbs(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
  referring_function = "displayCarbs";
  myComboBox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler);
}

function displayCarbs(event:Event):void 
{
  if (referring_function == "displayCarbs") 
  { myComboBox2.dataProvider = new DataProvider(carbItems); }
  if (referring_function == "displayOthers") 
  { myComboBox2.dataProvider = new DataProvider(otherItems); }
  // etc etc
}
```

I cant remember right now if you need `==` or just `=` when checking the **If statement** against strings.

Comment: You _always_ need `==` when checking one object against the other. `=` will _always_ set the first object equal to the second object, regardless of datatype or if it is in a conditional or not.

Answer (score 1):

I know there is an accepted answer already, but based on what I gleaned about the problem, here is a solution that wouldn't require adding another variable to check :

```
function displayCarbs(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
  myComboBox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler);
}

function changeHandler(event:Event):void 
{
     var comboBox:ComboBox = event.target as ComboBox;

     if (comboBox.dataProvider == uniqueProvider)
     {
           myComboBox2.dataProvider = new DataProvider(appropriateItems);
     }
}
```

This should work if the second dataProvider is determined based on the first dataProvider. This of course requires that your uniqueProvider is a class member variable so it has scope within the handler.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it makes logical sense to me. I will try and implement it at the end of the design process when I refactor code